# Folium and ColorMap -- is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, folium, colormap

The problem in question is: Object of type LinearColormap is not JSON serializable

```
maps['Zona de tarifa'] = maps['Zona de tarifa'].astype('int')
linear = cm.LinearColormap(["green", "yellow", "red"], vmin=maps['Zona de tarifa'].min(), vmax=maps['Zona de tarifa'].max())
```

```
map = folium.Map(location=[maps.new_latitud.mean(), maps.new_longitud.mean()], zoom_start=14, control_scale=True)
for index, location_info in maps.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["new_latitud"], location_info["new_longitud"]],icon=folium.Icon(color=linear),popup=location_info["Cliente"]+' '+location_info["Conductor"]).add_to(map)
map
```

I want to add color to my markers but that markers related to the variable or atributte "zona de tarifa" but i can't make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the colors available for markers are limited, you can color-code them by specifying colors from the color list. We have applied your code using sample data.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import random

maps = pd.DataFrame({'new_latitud': [random.uniform(36, 43.48) for _ in range(10)],
                   'new_longitud': [random.uniform(-9.18, 3.19) for _ in range(10)],
                   'Zona de tarifa': [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10)]})

# List of colors available for icons
colors= ['lightgray', 'darkred', 'lightgreen', 'green', 'pink', 'darkgreen', 'lightblue', 'darkpurple', 'black', 
 'lightred', 'gray', 'orange', 'cadetblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'beige', 'white', 'darkblue', 'red']

m = folium.Map(location=[maps.new_latitud.mean(), maps.new_longitud.mean()], zoom_start=6, control_scale=True)

for index, location_info in maps.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["new_latitud"], location_info["new_longitud"]],
                  icon=folium.Icon(color=colors[int(location_info['Zona de tarifa'])]),
                  #popup=location_info["Cliente"]+' '+location_info["Conductor"]
                 ).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I have to re-write my question, I want that the color is asociated to 'Zona de tarifa' , there are 10 'Zona de tarifa' I want that each zone have a different color , sorry bad english/ Each zone have to has a different color.

Comment: I made a mistake. I updated the method to set the value by retrieving it from the data frame column, not the index.

Comment: I also learned from your question that there is a limit to the number of colors you can put on a marker. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)